# Comparar array usando 2 valores

Tags: php

Preciso criar um array de produtos utilizando outro array de produtos.

No primeiro array existe o mesmo produto várias vezes, já o segundo preciso inserir somente os produtos quando não repetem. Se repete eu tenho que somar a quantidade do produto.

Outro detalhe importante é que o produto utiliza 2 chaves para identificar, produto  e tamanho. Minha Dúvida é como fazer esse `existeProdutoNoArray2`.

```
$produtos1 = array(
       array('produto'=>1,'tamanho'=>20,'quantidade'=>2)
       array('produto'=>1,'tamanho'=>21,'quantidade'=>3)
       array('produto'=>1,'tamanho'=>22,'quantidade'=>5)
       array('produto'=>3,'tamanho'=>20,'quantidade'=>1)
       array('produto'=>3,'tamanho'=>21,'quantidade'=>1)
       array('produto'=>3,'tamanho'=>22,'quantidade'=>2)
       array('produto'=>1,'tamanho'=>20,'quantidade'=>3)
       array('produto'=>1,'tamanho'=>21,'quantidade'=>1)
       array('produto'=>1,'tamanho'=>22,'quantidade'=>2)
);

$produtos2 = array();
foreach ($produtos1 as $key => $produto) {
      if(existeProdutoNoArray2){

      }else{
      $produtoTam = array('produto'=>$produto['produto'],'tamanho'=>$produto['tamanho'],'quantidade'=>$produto['quantidade']);
      array_push($produtos2,$produtoTam);
      }
}
```

Tentei usar o `in_array` assim:

```
in_array(array($produto['produto'],$produto['quantidade']),
array_column($produtos2,array('produto','tamanho'))
```

Mas não deu certo porque parece que o `in_array` aceita somente 1 parâmetro. 
O resultado deveria ser assim:

```
$produtos2 = array(
           array('produto'=>1,'tamanho'=>20,'quantidade'=>5)
           array('produto'=>1,'tamanho'=>21,'quantidade'=>4)
           array('produto'=>1,'tamanho'=>22,'quantidade'=>7)
           array('produto'=>3,'tamanho'=>20,'quantidade'=>1)
           array('produto'=>3,'tamanho'=>21,'quantidade'=>1)
           array('produto'=>3,'tamanho'=>22,'quantidade'=>2)
    );
```

Comment: Poderia colocar exemplos do array que você possui?

Comment: Editei a questão colocando um exemplo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O mais simples será você gerar um array associativo utilizando como chave um índice que seja equivalente entre os itens que precisa acumular. Como você quer acumulas as quantidades com base no produto e no tamanho, basta gerar uma chave que utiliza esses dois últimos valores:

```php
$produtos2 = [];

foreach ($produtos1 as $produto) {
  $indice = "{$produto['produto']}-{$produto['tamanho']}";

  if (!isset($produtos2[$indice])) {
    $produtos2[$indice] = $produto;
    continue;
  }

  $produtos2[$indice]["quantidade"] += $produto["quantidade"];
}

$produtos2 = array_values($produtos2);
```

Assim o resultado será:

```
array (
  0 =>
  array (
    'produto' => 1,
    'tamanho' => 20,
    'quantidade' => 5,
  ),
  1 =>
  array (
    'produto' => 1,
    'tamanho' => 21,
    'quantidade' => 4,
  ),
  2 =>
  array (
    'produto' => 1,
    'tamanho' => 22,
    'quantidade' => 7,
  ),
  3 =>
  array (
    'produto' => 3,
    'tamanho' => 20,
    'quantidade' => 1,
  ),
  4 =>
  array (
    'produto' => 3,
    'tamanho' => 21,
    'quantidade' => 1,
  ),
  5 =>
  array (
    'produto' => 3,
    'tamanho' => 22,
    'quantidade' => 2,
  ),
)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/SubstantialVioletredEmbed)</sup>

Comment: Deu certinho com o que eu preciso. Obrigado